# Are frozen organic blueberries kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation, fruits, bugs, chazaka

Do frozen organic blueberries require certification / checking for insects?  Apparently, according to the CRC and  Star-K, frozen blueberries [should not need kosher certification](https://www.kashrut.com/Alerts/?alert=A4646).  Is this also the case with "organic" frozen blueberries, such as frozen [Kirkland Signature Organic Blueberries](https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/kirkland-signature-organic-blueberries%2C-3-lbs.product.100206942.html), which [possibly have a higher risk of infestation](https://www.crcweb.org/NewFruitandVeglist.pdf)?

Comment: Is this a practical question, therefor off-topic?

Comment: @Mordechai hypothetical of course.

Answer (score 2):

As per the reply I just received from the CRC, they only recommend it for pureeing.